# power_binary question-This loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop

Tags: dafny

```
function method pow(m:int, n: int):int
requires n>=0
{
    if  n==0 then 1 
    else if n==1 then m
    else if n%2!=0 then m*pow(m,n-1)
    else  pow(m,n/2)*pow(m,n/2)
}


method check_even_power(x:int, y: int)
   requires  y>=0;
   requires  y % 2 == 0;
   ensures   pow(x, y / 2) * pow(x, y / 2) == pow(x, y);
{

}


method check_power(x:int, y: int)
   requires y%2!=0
   requires y>=0
   ensures  pow(x, y) == x * pow(x, y - 1);
{}


method power_binary(m:int, n: int) returns (Result: int)
   requires  n >= 0;
   ensures   Result == pow(m, n);
{
   var x, y: int;

   Result := 1;
   x := m;
   y := n;  
   while (y != 0)
   invariant  y >= 0;
   invariant  pow(m, n) == Result * pow(x, y) ;
   {
      if (y % 2 == 0)
      {
         check_even_power(x, y);
         x := x * x;
         y := y / 2;
      }
      else
      {
         check_power(x, y);
         Result := Result * x;
         y := y - 1;
      }
   }
}
```

i wanner know why compiler mentions me that This loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop.And i try to get the counter example,and it gets that m=1,n=20733,y=20733,why the code gets to while(y!=0),y becomes 20730,how to solve it？

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you debug this sort of thing.

I suggest you start by copying the failing invariant to the end of each `if` branch, because that lets you see which branch (or both) has the problem. The `if` statement in the loop then looks like this:

```
if y % 2 == 0 {
  check_even_power(x, y);
  x := x * x;
  y := y / 2;
  assert pow(m, n) == Result * pow(x, y);
} else {
  check_power(x, y);
  Result := Result * x;
  y := y - 1;
  assert  pow(m, n) == Result * pow(x, y);
}
```

You will get an error for the first of these assertions, but no error report for the second. This is good, for it tells you to focus your attention on the "then" branch.

Next, if you want to prove a condition X after an assignment `a := E;`, then the condition you have to prove prior to the assignment is X but with every occurrence of `a` replaced by `E`. In your case, there are two assignments before the assertion, so applying these substitutions makes your "then" branch look like this:

```
check_even_power(x, y);
assert pow(m, n) == Result * pow(x * x, y / 2);  // (2)
x := x * x;
assert pow(m, n) == Result * pow(x, y / 2);  // (1)
y := y / 2;
assert pow(m, n) == Result * pow(x, y);  // (0)
```

The verifier now complains about (2), but not about (1) or (0). This means that if you can prove (2), everything else will prove as well.

To prove (2), you have to work a bit more. I think the best technique to figure out what's wrong here is to use a proof calculation, which you do with the `calc` statement. Start by adding the equality of (2) into a `calc` statement that you place just before assertion (2):

```
check_even_power(x, y);
calc {
  pow(m, n);
==  // error
  Result * pow(x * x, y / 2);
}
assert pow(m, n) == Result * pow(x * x, y / 2);
```

The verifier will now complain that it cannot prove the step in the `calc`. I wrote `// error` above to indicate where the verifier is complaining. With this `calc` statement, the verifier no longer complains about assertion (2). This is good, because now all you need to focus on is to finish the `calc`.

Let's start from the top of the `calc`. What do you know about `pow(m, n)`? Well, you can use the loop invariant on entry to the loop. So you can add the following step to the calculation:

```
check_even_power(x, y);
calc {
  pow(m, n);
==  // the invariant on entry
  Result * pow(x, y);
==  // error
  Result * pow(x * x, y / 2);
}
```

Next, how to make the `pow(x, y)` in the middle line be more like the `pow(x * x, y / 2)` in the last line? Use the property you get from `check_even_power(x, y)`:

```
check_even_power(x, y);
calc {
  pow(m, n);
==  // the invariant on entry
  Result * pow(x, y);
==  // check_even_power(x, y)
  Result * (pow(x, y / 2) * pow(x, y / 2));
==   // error
  Result * pow(x * x, y / 2);
}
```

I kept the parentheses around `(pow(x, y / 2) * pow(x, y / 2))`, because I wanted to make sure that the multiplications would not re-associate in some way. As it turns out, multiplication for proof purposes is left-associative, so you don't need parentheses. My suggestion is that you add parentheses at first to make sure the proof step is doing what you expect it to do. Then, if that works, try removing parentheses or cleaning up the formula to your liking. You can also do the clean-up in an additional step in the proof calculation.

Let me now insert a tip: You have declared `check_even_power` and `check_power` as methods. This works, but can be improved. Those two methods are there just to help the proof, so I suggest you declare them with `lemma` instead of with `method`. This also means you can refer to them in a *hint* in the proof calculation, which makes your proof look nice and isolates the use of the lemma property to that step in the calculation. The result then looks like this:

```
calc {
  pow(m, n);
==  // the invariant on entry
  Result * pow(x, y);
==  { check_even_power(x, y); }
  Result * (pow(x, y / 2) * pow(x, y / 2));
==   // error
  Result * pow(x * x, y / 2);
}
```

Now, if you could only prove the last step, you'd be done. But proving `pow(a, b) * pow(a, b)` to be equal to `pow(a * a, b)` requires an inductive proof. Hence, what you need to do is define another lemma, which states this property. Then, replace my comment `// error` with an appropriate call to the new lemma. The lemma call will be in a hint, just like the call to `check_even_power`, so you'll place it in curly braces.

When the proof goes through, you can clean things up to your taste. For example, you can remove some of the `assert` statements that I had you add above for the purposes of debugging the problem.

Comment: Thank for your answer very much,now I find the way how to solve these questions in my code.